# How do i get the value from a tinyMCE textbox using jquery?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am trying to get a the value of a textbox that is using tinyMCE (jQuery Version) but when i do i get no content from the textbox. See my code below;

```
var content = $( "#content_textarea" ).val();
alert(content);
```

Also i am not using a form and the code is activated using a button.

I have also tried this code;

```
var content = tinyMCE.get('content_textarea').getContent();
alert(content);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You could make this easier to answer by providing more relevant details.  Such as, what the html you are calling this on looks like, and also POTENTIALLY, what TinyMCE transforms your HTML into.

Comment: try `tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();`?

Comment: are you using the jquery build of tinymce or the regular build (which i strongly suggest to use)?

Comment: @goldenparrot tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(); works perfect but i will be loading multiple instances of tinyMCE in the same page so this would not work in that case?

Comment: right. it'll only get the activeEditor's content which can be only one. obviously. so i guess the original problem should be solved.

Comment: If you have more tinymces on the page you can use tinyMCE.editors[0].getContent()

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var editor='content_textarea';
var content =tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
alert(content);
```

Or if you don't like that, you can do:

```
tinyMCE.triggerSave();
var content =$('#content_textarea').val();
alert(content);
```

Both work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
tinymce.get("original textarea id").getContent()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation here:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/jQuery_Plugin

You should use:

```
// Gets the contents from a specific editor
alert($('#someeditor').html());
```

Answer (score -1):

ive had the same problem with ckeditor... mybe this is of interest.

> CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].getData();

helped me out....whereby editor1 is the name of the instance

Comment: -1 this question is about tinymce. CKEDITOR commands are of no help here!